# cinelerra error 404 not found after apt update

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, apt

After make an "sudo apt update" statement in my Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS a get
the next error:

```
  Err:20 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic Release                                       
    404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.219.241 443]
  Obj:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic       InRelease                                      
  Obj:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho                
  E: El repositorio «https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18  bionic Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
  N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma  segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
  N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios
```

I have tried with the manually installation following:

```
  https://www.cinelerra-gg.org/forum/forum-miscellaneous/installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-404-error/
```

but u get another error 404:

```
  Conectando con www.cinelerra-gg.org (www.cinelerra-gg.org) [104.21.62.38]:443... conectado.
  Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 404 Not Found
  2021-02-18 11:01:31 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

the object is not there.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). Please ask on [ubuntu.se] instead.

Comment: So sorry,I was in a hurry. I'm going to change the place of this question.Thanks @GAD3R

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic main
```

Add `cinelerra` repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa
```

It will add the missing gpg key.